# Difference between handling errors in web.xml and spring mvc config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, exception

I have an **Spring MVC web application**, that has a `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolver` that catches all exceptions and maps them to corresponding pre-defined error views and http status code. This `HandlerExceptionResolver` is defined in `webmvc-config.xml` file under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Now, my client insists that I need to also map http status codes and exceptions in my `web.xml` file, which I am failing to understand because I don't see in what case my Spring MVC app would fail to catch an error, that would need to be handled by `web.xml`.

With that being said, this led me to the question of **what is the fundamental difference between catching errors in `web.xml` and my custom spring mvc config file**.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a generic error handler for `java.lang.Exception` in the `web.xml`, just in case that anything escapes Spring MVC error handling mechanism. For example, you misconfigure something in the Spring MVC infrastructure itself, so Spring error handlers don't even get a chance to handle the error.

However, you should not re-map http status codes in the `web.xml`, because then the container will intercept all the generated error responses returned from Spring MVC and replace them with results generated by the error handlers defined in the `web.xml`. Of course, you could take care that the error handlers invoke the same logic as Spring ones, so that returned error responses are the same, but obviously that's quite an unnecessary work.

I would say that you should discuss this with your client in more detail and explain them the concepts and best practices related to [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller).

Answer (score 1):

Both mechanisms works. However the HandlerExceptionResolver is more flexible than the standard web.xml mappings in web.xml. The HandlerExceptionResolver provides you with a programmatic approach to handling exceptions as compared to the error mappings in web.xml.

For example you can override a provided implementation or implement a custom HandlerExceptionResolver with custom logic e.g sending an email to a system administrator before forwarding to your view.

Another advantage is that your handler exception resolver is a Spring bean which can have access to all services in your application context.

However you have to ensure that your HandlerExceptionResolver maps all possible exception.If you have an entry for Throwable then this should be sufficient.

Your client is just being cautious in case your HandlerExceptionResolver misses some exceptions. If its properly setup the web.xml mappings becomes redudant

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But why Throwable? Wouldnt catching `java.lang.Exception` be sufficient? I am asking this because the client also insists that I catch `RuntimeException` in the `web.xml`. Which doesn't make sense to me because I am already catching `java.lang.Exception` in `web.xml`.

Comment: Throwable covers both Exception and Error